# Heroku website rails cant log in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, authentication

Hi everyone I had a website working on localhost:3000 and after deploying it to heroku it wont log in either through email, facebook or google.

It says...
We're sorry, but something went wrong.

If you are the application owner check the logs for more information.

This is the log, as far as I am aware.
2016-07-27T14:19:43.719220+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/auth/facebook" for 178.167.254.130 at 2016-07-27 14:19:43 +0000
2016-07-27T14:19:44.385948+00:00 app[web.1]:   User Load (2.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = $1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["email", "barryjamesreeves@gmail.com"]]
2016-07-27T14:19:44.376866+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"code"=>"AQAimEd3zlA9aomiPb115KoKJ9ntclITq7BNYfEz8VezLOAIBry-mSaGF2zbFL0hkz2g7l_YS7fdK89AuFQ7CeQoF7O42hEk8jEcvAfeJl9UeeQu-QiAF5RO8y1YcMhfj4HEOrXjVXuXT_vY0GSQQ15ZUAVaByR6H8aPwtRcDZnyS2orAi36gew0gP1aG3qGsxGlIIDt6o_LShm--zog3twAbFe4vHLXSJtdWxdG_G4pMCBv5oqzq84mS7avF0qDlXOGS5HfGcyODFlbh8t1rqjMXJNCUVBm-7J0WLMvncTQTawuhRQAvJAWJRr7WDCEYXu4SUsvOAxvzQ5KrfECE4Ji", "state"=>"84f33935f2d2f759cbf1b9bb5025bfdbfba95bb82f9972a1"}
2016-07-27T14:19:44.483905+00:00 app[web.1]:   User Exists (1.8ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = 'barryjamesreeves@gmail.com' LIMIT 1
2016-07-27T14:19:44.390107+00:00 app[web.1]:   User Load (1.6ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."provider" = $1 AND "users"."uid" = $2  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["provider", "facebook"], ["uid", "638781552953110"]]
2016-07-27T14:19:44.376844+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by OmniauthCallbacksController#facebook as HTML
2016-07-27T14:19:44.250584+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/auth/facebook/callback?code=AQAimEd3zlA9aomiPb115KoKJ9ntclITq7BNYfEz8VezLOAIBry-mSaGF2zbFL0hkz2g7l_YS7fdK89AuFQ7CeQoF7O42hEk8jEcvAfeJl9UeeQu-QiAF5RO8y1YcMhfj4HEOrXjVXuXT_vY0GSQQ15ZUAVaByR6H8aPwtRcDZnyS2orAi36gew0gP1aG3qGsxGlIIDt6o_LShm--zog3twAbFe4vHLXSJtdWxdG_G4pMCBv5oqzq84mS7avF0qDlXOGS5HfGcyODFlbh8t1rqjMXJNCUVBm-7J0WLMvncTQTawuhRQAvJAWJRr7WDCEYXu4SUsvOAxvzQ5KrfECE4Ji&state=84f33935f2d2f759cbf1b9bb5025bfdbfba95bb82f9972a1" for 178.167.254.130 at 2016-07-27 14:19:44 +0000
2016-07-27T14:19:44.480409+00:00 app[web.1]:    (1.6ms)  BEGIN
2016-07-27T14:19:44.252793+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2016-07-27T14:19:44.252730 #3]  INFO -- omniauth: (facebook) Callback phase initiated.
2016-07-27T14:19:44.688539+00:00 app[web.1]:   User Load (1.7ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."provider" = $1 AND "users"."uid" = $2 AND "users"."confirmation_token" = $3  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["provider", "facebook"], ["uid", "638781552953110"], ["confirmation_token", "7e801f409f1a87a3e65cb42cc124e971ec3e7f7caf4f441795985c6d9110969a"]]
2016-07-27T14:19:44.693755+00:00 app[web.1]:   SQL (1.7ms)  INSERT INTO "users" ("provider", "uid", "fullname", "email", "image", "encrypted_password", "created_at", "updated_at", "confirmation_token", "confirmation_sent_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10) RETURNING "id"  [["provider", "facebook"], ["uid", "638781552953110"], ["fullname", "Barry Reeves"], ["email", "barryjamesreeves@gmail.com"], ["image", "http://graph.facebook.com/638781552953110/picture"], ["encrypted_password", "$2a$10$LnDgeb0oc.2oczdFwYeizeX2tuQDoC8aF.jJ02ddBSM8wxlhxzaZy"], ["created_at", "2016-07-27 14:19:44.484330"], ["updated_at", "2016-07-27 14:19:44.484330"], ["confirmation_token", "SzgGE4Z67As_h-fdmXgR"], ["confirmation_sent_at", "2016-07-27 14:19:44.688985"]]
2016-07-27T14:19:44.734814+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered devise/mailer/confirmation_instructions.html.erb (1.9ms)
2016-07-27T14:19:44.734891+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-07-27T14:19:44.734893+00:00 app[web.1]: Devise::Mailer#confirmation_instructions: processed outbound mail in 38.3ms
2016-07-27T14:19:44.736688+00:00 app[web.1]:    (1.6ms)  ROLLBACK
2016-07-27T14:19:44.738075+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 361ms (ActiveRecord: 13.8ms)
2016-07-27T14:19:44.740664+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-07-27T14:19:44.740666+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (Missing host to link to! Please provide the :host parameter, set default_url_options[:host], or set :only_path to true):
2016-07-27T14:19:44.740667+00:00 app[web.1]:     2: 
2016-07-27T14:19:44.740667+00:00 app[web.1]:     3:

You can confirm your account email through the link below:

2016-07-27T14:19:44.740668+00:00 app[web.1]:     4: 
2016-07-27T14:19:44.740669+00:00 app[web.1]:     5:

<%= link_to 'Confirm my account', confirmation_url(@resource, confirmation_token: @token) %>

2016-07-27T14:19:44.740670+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/devise/mailer/confirmation_instructions.html.erb:5:in `_app_views_devise_mailer_confirmation_instructions_html_erb__4041444012376916285_69837330575780'
2016-07-27T14:19:44.740671+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/models/user.rb:20:in`from_omniauth'
2016-07-27T14:19:44.740671+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb:4:in `facebook'
2016-07-27T14:19:44.740672+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-07-27T14:19:44.740673+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-07-27T14:19:37.167494+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=gentle-escarpment-62627.herokuapp.com request_id=02fbf786-95af-4421-ae32-ae221c0ea302 fwd="178.167.254.130" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=88ms status=200 bytes=5829

Any help appreciated
thanks

Comment: did you change the redirect_to url in developer's account of google ,fb

Comment: Could you paste the logs showing the error plz? There is no error in the logs you provided.

Comment: not enough logs there

Comment: OK i added the logs... Sorry if its hard to read. Yea I added redirect url to facebook... thanks for your help